Why isn't the space complexity of program adding values to a letter keyed hash map linear?
Imagine a program that takes a string of length p as an argument, and counts each letter by adding 1 for every occurrence using a hash map that only uses the 26 letters of the English alphabet as keys. I've seen this type program described as O(1) in terms of space complexity (see the quote below). The reasoning being that since we know the size of the key set is capped, the space complexity is constant.
From Tech Interview Handbook:

Often you will need to count the frequency of characters in a string.
The most common way of doing that is by using a hash table/map in your
language of choice. If your language has a built-in Counter class like
Python, ask if you can use that instead.
If you need to keep a counter of characters, a common mistake is to
say that the space complexity required for the counter is O(n). The
space required for a counter of a string of latin characters is O(1)
not O(n). This is because the upper bound is the range of characters,
which is usually a fixed constant of 26. The input set is just
lowercase Latin characters.

How can we say this, when it seems to me that the size of the map in memory will obviously grow proportionally to the size of p? If we give the program an input of length p+1, won't the size of the map (specifically the integers containing the count of the characters in the input, thus the map itself) necessarily be larger than if we provide an input of length p?

No. No matter how long the input is, there are at most 26 entries in the map.

And all integers are the same size, unless you're using a language with unbounded integers (e.g. Python or Lisp). And even then, the size of an integer generally won't increase until it exceeds 2^31.

@Barmar Thanks you for your response and formatting. I understand there are only that many entries, but doesn't that count of 26 entries ignore the size of an entry itself? Sure, there may be only 26 entries, but with a large enough input string, one entry could be 10kb or 10gb... hypothetically... which isn't constant

In most languages, all integers are a fixed size, typically 32 bits or 64 bits. So it doesn't matter whether the count is 10kb or 10gb.

Note that 32 bits is large enough to hold up to 2x10^10.

And 64 bits is almost 10^20.

@lordgort "one entry could be 10kb or 10gb" - you're not imagining that the entries have to store the characters from the input string, are you?  The entries only need to store the count of how many such characters have been seen so far, and each extra bit in the counter allows you to track twice as many characters.  (Separately, for contiguous character sets or ranges it's better to use an array instead of a hash map - can access the correct counter without calling any hash function or having to resolve collisions, but the algorithmic complexity is the same either way).

I believe OP is saying that the input string needs to be stored in memory (at least temporarily).

No, that is not how HashMaps works.
Why O(1) Space Complexity?
Remember: Space complexity is extra-space(thus don't include input space) your algorithm needs depending on the input size.
HashMap<Character, Integer> here has fixed size containing only 26 keys representing each Character(1 byte), and 26 values corresponding to each key (which can be a 4 byte integer thus can store values upto 2 Billion).
Irrespective of your input string size, you only need this constant space of HashMap to keep count of characters. Suppose if your string becomes significantly large say in trillions, then you can just change the value type of HashMap to Long(16 Byte) to hold even much bigger values for each character, again still your extra space is independent of input size and constant, thus has Space Complexity of O(1).

As you said, the hash map is gonna have at its most 26 entries/characters, with each one holding an integer that might ocupy 4 to 8 bytes - 4 bytes makes already possible to reach: 2,147,483,647 as an integer.
Thinking about that, it doesn't matter how long your string argument (p) is, the entries are gonna still be capped to the 26 characters of the hash map and the space ocuppied (4 to 8 bytes) are never gonna change. Therefore, the space complexity does not grow with the p size, meaning it's not linear but constant -> O(1).
:)

Before talking about why it's constant space, let's define what space complexity means.
Space complexity describes how space varies with the size of the input.
"Constant space" doesn't mean "the same space every time", rather it means "no matter how large the input, the space used is at most some constant amount". Now imagine you change the algorithm slightly to prime the map assigning a count of zero to every letter; the space used by the map will never grow no matter how big the input String. Not priming the map just delays the maps size from reaching the primed size.
